# Proof mode definitions in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Can anyone give me some good source on how to read proof mode-definitions (an example is given:)

```
Definition A (ss: FSS) (n:nat)
             (s: {s:S | state_is_wf s
                            /\ RESS.get_element n (proj1_sig ss) = Some s})
    : FS.
    destruct s. destruct a.
    refine (exist _ x _).
    apply H.
  Defined.
```

where 'FSS', 'FS' and 'S' are sig types defined earlier. I know what the inidividual tactics 'destruct', 'refine' and 'apply' do, but in a proof term for
a definition, I can't read this proof without probably compiling (I cannot compile these files, can only read their source code.) Can anyone either help me with how to read such definitions or point me to some source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without compiling the definition (and without seeing the definitions of `FS` and `FSS`), it is impossible, but we can still guess a bit. The `destruct` tactic creates a `match with` construct on `s`, which is of type `sig`, which has a unique constructor `exist`. There is no `a` among the arguments of the function, so `a` is either a global symbol, or it is a variable created by the first `destruct`. Let us assume it is the latter. Same thing for `x`.

Tactic `refine` creates a term, possibly with holes. Term `exist _ x _` contains two holes. The first `_` is filled by Coq, but the last one presumably has to be filled by the user, so that is what `apply H` is for. As for `H`, let us assume it comes from one of the previous `destruct`.

Note that `apply` might first decompose inductive values with only one constructor. So, if `H` happens to be of type `A /\ B` (which it would be if it comes from the first `destruct`), `apply H` might actually be `apply (proj1 H)` or `apply (proj2 H)`. Anyway, since the proof is now finished, this `apply` is presumably `exact`.

So, there are numerous possibilities. Here is an example:

```
Definition A ss n s :=
  match s with
  | exist _ a H =>
    match a with
    | ... x ... =>         (* H could come from there too *)
      exist _ x (proj1 H)  (* or (proj2 H), or plain H *)
    end
  end.
```